# Can you play Guitar Hero using Rock Band 3's new cymbals?

Tags: rock-band-3, guitar-hero

Guitar Hero supports both 4-lane and 5-lane drums mode.  I assumed it wouldn't be possible to play 5-lane drums in Guitar Hero using the Rock Band cymbals, but then I found [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001V6SO5U), which claim to work with Guitar Hero.

Is it possible to play 5-lane drums using a Rock Band drumset and the new cymbals?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's unlikely that anything other than Guitar Hero drums will work. I have an Ion kit with three cymbals; it works fine with Rock Band 2 and 3, but shows up as a "normal" 4-color kit in GH: Monsters of Rock.

It's disappointing, because while I greatly prefer the Rock Band series now, I enjoy variety, but I'm not going to buy another kit just to get a better GH experience. (I tried that with a GH guitar to use the slide/tap stuff, and that wasn't really worth it IMHO.)